# Is there a way to replace all the bullet lists with numbered list in docx file using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I've been trying to find a way to change all the bullet lists in a docx file to number list using python-docx. So far, I've tried using `paragraph.style` attribute. Doing something like this:

```
if paragraph.style.name == 'Bullet List':
    paragraph.style = styles['List Number']
```

It works on basic docx files but sometimes, with more complex documents, `paragraph.style.name` returns something like `'Body Text'` even though the given paragraph appears as a bullet list in the document. I was just wondering if it's possible to achieve this using python-docx library or I might have to look for something else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. What you're seeing are bullets applied to a paragraph using the toolbar button, which applies the bullet formatting directly to the paragraph. Any formatting applied at the paragraph level (the lowest level) overrides formatting inherited from a style.

What you'd need to do to fix this is to remove the manual paragraph formatting (possibly by selecting paragraphs and pressing Ctrl-Q) as described here and in other web resources as well I'm sure: https://www.okbar.org/lpt_articles/removing-formatting-from-word-documents/

After those "overrides" are removed, the style should be free to do its work.

There is no `python-docx` API counterpart to "remove-all-formatting". If you wanted to do it programmatically you would need to manipulate the XML yourself. `python-docx` can get you to the paragraph element with `p = paragraph._p` and then `print(p.xml)` can show you what the XML looks like, but from there you're on your own to manipulate that XML subtree with `lxml` calls. Search on `python-docx workaround function` for some ideas on what that looks like.

Comment: I had the idea that to do this I have to manipulate the XML itself. Thank you for this this really helped me.